# Vectorise Within-Groups Sum of Squares in R

Tags: r, sums-of-squares, canonical-correlation

I've got a multivariate dataset (p=2) that I'm trying to calculate the W matrix for use in canonical variates analysis

If each $x_{kj}$ is the jth observational unit from the kth group, and $\bar{x}_k$ is the mean vector for the kth group, then:
$W = \sum\limits_{k=1}^K{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_k}{(x_{kj} - \bar{x}_k)(x_{kj} - \bar{x}_k)^T}}$

Doing this as a set of nested loops is easy enough, but I cannot for the life of me see how to vectorise this.

Hopefully this code doesn't make you want to poke your eyes out, but here's my first attempt (the relevant stuff is at the bottom):

```
#dataframe setup K=6 (one for each sex/rug combination), n=4 for every group

df = data.frame(rbind(
      cbind(rep("M", 4), rep("A", 4), c(5,5,9,7), c(6,4,9,6)),
      cbind(rep("M", 4), rep("B", 4), c(7,7,9,6), c(6,7,12,8)),
      cbind(rep("M", 4), rep("C", 4), c(21,14,17,12), c(15,11,12,10)),
      cbind(rep("F", 4), rep("A", 4), c(7,6,9,8), c(10,6,7,10)),
      cbind(rep("F", 4), rep("B", 4), c(10,8,7,6), c(13,7,6,9)),
      cbind(rep("F", 4), rep("C", 4), c(16,14,14,10), c(12,9,8,5))
      ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(df) = c("Sex", "Drug", "X1", "X2")

df$Sex = as.factor(df$Sex)
df$Drug = as.factor(df$Drug)
df$X1 = as.numeric(df$X1)
df$X2 = as.numeric(df$X2)
df$Group = as.factor(paste(df$Sex, df$Drug, sep=""))

xbar = lapply(df[,3:4], mean)

groupMeans = aggregate(cbind(X1, X2)~Group,df,mean)

#within groups SS calculation

W = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
for(k in unique(df$Group)){
  groupEntries = subset(df, select = c(X1,X2), subset=(Group == k))
  xbar = subset(groupMeans, select = c(X1,X2), subset=(Group == k))
  n = dim(groupEntries)[[1]]
  for(j in 1:n){
    centred = as.matrix(groupEntries[j,] - xbar)
    W = W + t(centred) %*% centred
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following more efficient approach:

```
W_groups <- by(df[3:4], df$Group, function(x) {
  centred <- scale(x, scale = FALSE)
  t(centred) %*% centred
})

Reduce("+", W_groups)
```

The result:

```
     X1    X2
X1 94.5  76.5
X2 76.5 114.0
```

In the first step, the function `by` is used to apply a function to the columns 3 and 4 of your data frame (`df[3:4]`) grouped by `df$Group`. The command `scale(x, scale = FALSE)` is used to center the columns before the matrix product `t(centred) %*% centred` is calculated.

The function `by` returns a list `W_groups` where one list element corresponds to the result for one group of data. We can add the matrices in the list with the `"+"` function. The function `Reduce` allows to use the list as an argument.